# tcp_ack in linux

Tags: linux, tcp, linux-kernel

Anybody knows is [tcp_ack()](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.2.1/net/ipv4/tcp_input.c#L3677)  calling for each incoming TCP-segment marked as ACK or in some special cases it doesn't happens?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are some exceptions:
1. A segment that was found to be invalid, before `tcp_ack` was called.
2. Sockets in time-wait state (I think).
3. SYN-ACK packets (which arrive, as they should, in the syn-sent state).

Comment: Yeap, if segment is invalid `tcp_ack` obviously didn't calling. 
SYN-ACK packets used only for connection initiation.
 But idea about time-wait state is interesting. I will check it.